# Removing my fork so I can fork again later on

Tags: git, github

I forked a github repo, did what I needed to do, and submitted a pull request.  When it goes through I'd like to get rid of my fork, at least locally, and fork again from master if the need arises.

What is a good way of going about this?  I don't mind that my fork still 'exists' in the GitHub repo.

I suppose I could simply remove the forked directory locally but want to be sure that won't cause trouble to someone else, who maybe (unlikely) forked my own repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once it's forked, it's under your namespace, so you can do whatever you want with it. If someone else has forked your fork, it will be under his own namespace. And if your pull request is merged, it's just a merge of code. You can easily [delete your fork](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository) and re-fork the main repo, if you wish.